# What does l stand for in this expression?

Tags: limits

When the limit is in the indeterminate form, in this case $0/0$. If we take a rational function $f(x) = g(x)/h(x)$ and $$\lim_{x\to\ a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a}[g(x)/h(x)] = g(a)/h(a)$$

Then we can re write $g(x)$ as $(x-a)^kg_1(x)$ where $k$ is the maximum powers of $(x-a)$ in $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ can be written as $(x-a)^lh_1(x)$ as $h(a)=0$. Now, if $k > l$ we have $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = [\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)^kg_1(x)]/[\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)^lh_1(x)]$$ And if $k<l$ then the limit is not defined. This is what's been given in my textbook and it makes sense. My question is does l in $h(x)$ denote the limit or is  just simply the power of $(x-a)$ in $h(x)$?

Comment: It is the power

Comment: It created so much confusion. At first it looked like 1 in my book and then I figured out it was l and I was even more confused.